# Should Elasticsearch running on EC2 be exposed with a Load Balancer or DNS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-eks, nginx-reverse-proxy

The Elasticsearch cluster (self-hosted on EC2) has 3 nodes in private subnets. I am looking to expose the service to an EKS in another VPC, connected via the VPC peering. Initially, I was thinking to have a Load Balancer in front of Elasticsearch but I understand that using a Load Balancer to talk to Elasticsearch APIs is not recommended.

Is using DNS the best option to connect to Elasticsearch from EKS? Any other suggestions such as NGINX?

Comment: When you said DNS, do you mean hitting the EC2 DNS directly? Why would you not want to do this? This is the simplest approach as I understand it.

Comment: I meant attaching an ENI and an A record via private DNS to point to that ENI. I'm actually after best practices whether I should use a Load Balancer or not.